# Word for people with interesting and for those with boring stories

Tags: word-request

What word can I use to describe people who frequently keep telling a long story in a boring way (i.e. they keep telling their life incidences in exaggerated way)?

In a similar vein, what word can I use to describe people who keep telling their life incidences in interesting and enjoyable ways?

Comment: If you like listening to them, they're [raconteurs](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/raconteur). If you don't, they're [bores](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/bore)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good word for the first type of person might be [blowhard](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/blowhard?s=t):  An exceptionally talkative and boastful person.  Or, perhaps they are a [windbag](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/windbag?s=t): someone with nothing to say, who takes all day to say it.

Going only slightly further afield, you might call them a [blatherer](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/blather?s=t), [babbler](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/babble?s=t), prattler, or chatterer.

Answer (score 0):

If a person is always exaggerating about his abilities or achievements, he is a [braggart](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/braggart).